# ES6: How do I reduce this array of objects to unique values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I've been spinning my wheels for way too long trying to work this out and I'm ready to throw my computer out the window. How might I reduce this array:

```
const array = [
  {'location': "Plovdiv", 'department': "Finance"},
  {'location': "Plovdiv", 'department': "Client & Employee Support"},
  {'location': "Plovdiv", 'department': "Client & Employee Support"},
  {'location': "London", 'department': "Engineering"},
  {'location': "London", 'department': "Engineering"},
  {'location': "Plovdiv", 'department': "Engineering"}
];
```

to this:

```
{'location': "Plovdiv", 'department': ["Finance", "Client & Employee Support", "Engineering"]},
{'location': "London", 'department': ["Engineering"]},
```

My goal is to remove the duplicate arrays in objects with location, and merge them as a single key. Where each key will have the corresponding departments as a list.

edit: I finally managed to figure it out with plain ol' JS, but it's bulky and features a LOT of looping that I could probably get rid of with a more modern approach.

```
let locArray = [];
  let newGrouping = [];

  // For each location
  for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i += 1) {
    // Check to see if the current locations is in the new locArray
    if (locArray.indexOf(locations[i].location) === -1) {
      // Get in there!
      locArray.push(locations[i].location);
    }
  }

  // Loop through the new set of unique locations
  for (let i = 0; i < locArray.length; i += 1) {
    let depArray = [];

    // Loop through our original locations array
    for (let j = 0; j < locations.length; j += 1) {
      // Check to see if the current unique location matches the current location
      // AND make sure that it's not already in depArray
      if (locArray[i] === locations[j].location && depArray.indexOf(locations[j].department) === -1) {
        // Get in there!
        depArray.push(locations[j].department);
      }
    }

    // Push our current unique location and its unique departments into a new object
    newGrouping.push({
      'location': locArray[i],
      'departments': depArray
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like you've spent some time writing code.  You should add your attempt to your question.

Comment: Here is the solution: https://jsbin.com/cenamajici/edit?js,console

Comment: That did it! Thanks, @roliroli

Comment: Bryan see below for an ES6 solution, not sure why it was down voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Set` and `map`

We want to uniquely key on `location` to do this we use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to ensure uniqueness.

```js
  // Notice we use the map function to pull just location. 
  new Set(array.map(({ location }) => location))
```

But now we need to iterate those unique keys and rebuild our array.
So we load the `Set` into an `Array`

```
 const unique = new Array(...new Set(array.map(({ location }) => location)))
```

Now we have an `array` of unique `location`, from here we can use a map function to build our desired `array` output.
Notice how as we build our final `array` of `object` the `department` parameter is rehydrated using a `filter` and `map` of the original array.

```
  [Unique Location Array].map(location => ({ 
          location, // ES6 the property name it is inferred
          department: array.filter(({ location: l}) => location === l)
                            .map(({ department }) => department)
          }));
```

```js
const array = [
  {'location': "Plovdiv", 'department': "Finance"},
  {'location': "Plovdiv", 'department': "Client & Employee Support"},
  {'location': "Plovdiv", 'department': "Client & Employee Support"},
  {'location': "London", 'department': "Engineering"},
  {'location': "London", 'department': "Engineering"},
  {'location': "Plovdiv", 'department': "Engineering"}
];

const unique = new Array(...new Set(array.map(({ location }) => location)))
                      .map(location => ({ 
                                        location,
                                        department: array.filter(({ location: l}) => location === l)
                                                         .map(({ department }) => department)
                                        }));
                                        
console.log(unique);
```